# Has any astronomer/physicist used geometry and trigonometry to calculate where the center of the universe is?

Tags: observational-astronomy, observable-universe

Since we are pretty sure that the universe is expanding at a steady and accelerating rate wouldn’t it be possible to simultaneously observe 4 points (galaxies) that are all, as closely as we can tell, at a similar distance from our reference point to triangulate back and find the beginning point or location?

Comment: as discussed in [Why can't we determine the center of the universe](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/5978/7982) and [What is in the center of the universe?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/669/7982), current thinking is that the universe is much bigger than the *observable universe*, and since rate of expansion increases with distance from us, going outwards things get redder and dimmer and then finally become unobservable. However we don't know just how much bigger the whole universe is than what we can observe.

Comment: See also [Are there ways to estimate size of the "whole universe"?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/31793/7982) and (getting curiouser and curiouser as we go down the rabbit hole) [Is it "nonsense to even talk about" objects outside the observable universe not having gravitational influence on us? (finite speed of gravity)](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/44989/7982) and [How much of the Universe is invisible to us, and how does it affect our theories?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/32170/7982)

Comment: and [How is the gravitational effect of galaxies outside of the visible universe on galaxies within the visible universe currently modeled?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/35449/7982) and [If we watched extremely red-shifted galaxies near the edge of the observable universe for a very long time, how would they change? Would more appear?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/44703/7982). **However:** If you edited your question and changed it to "Has any astronomer/physicist TRIED TO use...?" and added the [history] tag to your question, I think it can be reopened and answered.

Comment: Or at least then a moderator might migrate it to [History of Science and Mathematics SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions). Now if you really want to "[bake your noodle](https://youtu.be/EUN1ClT9i9w?t=13)", check out [What is in the center of the universe?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/669/7982)